# SSIS Project validation fails if ServerName is parameterized but ConnectionString is not

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have a SSIS project containing 50 or so packages. A master package executes the child packages in the right sequence.
The project is deployed to an SSIS catalog and execution is invoked by a stored procedure with some control logic and error handling.
The Connection Managers are parameterised with values passed in from Environment variables setup in the IS catalogs. The ServerName and InitialCatalog properties of the connection manager are parameterised but the ConnectionString is not.
DelayValidation is set to False on all packages.

So far so good. This has been working in dev, test and production environments for quite a while.
When I deploy new a version of a project I like to validate the project in SSMS to make sure that all of the data structures in the live environment match those expected by the packages.

I now have a validation failure in my test environment which I believe is because the ConnectionString, last updated in VS debug environment is out of synch with the ServerName and InitialCatalog specified in the test systems environment variables. The ConnectionString in the package is pointing to a server with a schema difference compared to live.
So, my questions are: 
1. Does the ConnectionString string get rebuilt during SSMS driven validation or does it only get built during execution of the package?
2. If I set DelayValidation to True on this package then will it get validated during validation when it is installed in the catalog or will it only get validated at run time?

I think I was barking up the wrong tree and will dig deeper into the state of the databases that are being referred to in my packages.

My account doesn't seem to allow me to answer questions :-(
If someone else can put an answer in (any upvotes gratefully received and offered) then the question can be closed.

Comment: If you are using a variable to define the connection, which can change while the package is running, then you should be setting the `DelayValidation` property to true on nodes that make use of that connection.

Comment: Open an execution report for this erroneous execution, and check values of passed variables there. On your question #1 - connection string is updated before validation is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Connection Manager` properties get fully resolved before the individual package gets validated. As @Ferdipux says, you can see the property values at execution (if you filter on `Context Depth = 2` in the `Error Context` report) and you will see the value for the `ConnectionString` property correctly resolved from the `ServerName` and `InitialCatalog` variables set in the environment variables for the project. I don't think there is an issue with `SSIS`, it is likely that the database, referred to in the package, is still out of sync with your package metadata.